# meaning of 'accounted for'

Tags: word-usage

Although all coffee companies have increased prices on
all brands of coffee they sell, the increase in revenues is much higher than can
be accounted for by the increase in prices.

Answer (score 0):

To "account for" something is to explain what is happening to it, or what has happened to it. (Source: [Merriam-Webster: "Account For"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account%20for) definition 1.)

In this case the increase in revenues cannot be explained by the increase in prices: revenue is increasing more than prices.